# Is it possible to check if user have PM's enabled?

Tags: discord, chatbot, discord-jda, private-messaging

I'd like to know if there is a way to check if a User have Private Messages Enabled.

This Feature is for an Support Bot. Currently I use the GuildMessageRecievedEvent and send a Private Message to the User.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is not. You can only send a message and handle the failure:

```java
user.openPrivateChannel().submit()
    .thenCompose(channel -> channel.sendMessage(x).submit())
    .whenComplete((message, error) -> {
        if (error != null) failed();
        else success();
    });
```